# how to do eye blinking inside face recognition in flutter

Tags: flutter, face-recognition, blink

I am trying to make an app that contain eye blinking inside face recognition, but difficult to me to find resources about eye blinking. are there package or resources that I can read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use opencv in Python along with few other libs to detect the eye blinks.

Once you consume the video feed,

```
EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.3   

for rect in rects:
    # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
    # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
    # array
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
    # extract the left and right eye coordinates, then use the
    # coordinates to compute the eye aspect ratio for both eyes
    leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
    rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
    # EAR = eye aspect ratio
    leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)                     # important line
    rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)                   # important line
    # average the eye aspect ratio together for both eyes
    ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0
```

The variable 'ear' gives eye aspect ratio. Now, you compare if it is below threshold. e.g.

```
if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
    # eye is blinked. continue with your business logic.
```

For more details, please refer [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/24/eye-blink-detection-opencv-python-dlib/)  link.

Comment: I am trying same approach but can't get it? can anyone help me to understand how I can convert this to flutter?